# Custom activity designer with specific Expand\Collapse behavior

Tags: .net, designer, workflow-foundation-4

I am trying to create a designer for a custom WF4 activity with the Expand/Collapse ability with the following characteristics:

- when first added to the workflow designer (Visual Studio designer not a custom one) the activity should be collapsed.
- when double clicked on the activity, regardless if it is expanded or collapsed, the designer should open it in the "single activity mode" as expanded.

I have a version of the designer inspired from the one presented in: http://xhinker.com/2010/03/16/WF4CreateACustomActivity.aspx but the activity designer does not behaves as I would want. 
If I am using:  `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ShowExpanded}" Value="true">` the second characteristic is as expected but the first one obviously it isn't because when first added in the workflow designer the activity is present as expanded.
I tried to set the *ShowExpanded* value on false but then the second condition is not OK, the VS designer opening my activity as collapsed when double clicking on it.

Is there any way in which an activity designer fulfilling both conditions, would be possible to be implemented?

Also it would be great for me to find out if there is a way to "persist" the view state(Expanded or Collapsed) of a custom activity, so if the activity was collapsed (or expanded) when the containing workflow definition was last time viewed to be opened as collapsed (or expanded by case)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your last question, you can use the [ViewStateService](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mwinkle/archive/2009/12/06/wf4-viewstateservice.aspx) to store view state information in the workflow XAML file.

As for your first question, I believe you can force the activity to be collapsed on drop if, in the xaml, you set [ExpandState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.presentation.workflowviewelement.expandstate.aspx) to `false`.  Honestly, it is a little hard to understand what exactly is going on with your workflow designer that you're not happy with...

Comment: Given the fact that I have some activities with a significant number of arguments which can be set via the designer, and that in a workflow definition there can be quite a few of those activities, viewing and understanding the main flow of those workflow definitions with all activities expanded can be very difficult. So I need a way to make the main flow to be as easy to read as possible without forcing the person who is "reading" or creating it to collapse by hand the activities. And most important, those are the requirements for the activities designers :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer it helped me to complete this task.